# Can't access OBIEE analytics

Tags: weblogic, middleware, database-administration, obiee

I have a problem when I try to login to the OBI Analytics, it give me an error Unable to sign in although it is success in both console and EM with the same username and password of weblogic but when I try to access OBI Analytics is not accepted, I have checked all services are all up and running as mentioned in the attached files, any suggestion please

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHIam.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lympl.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried checking the bi server log?

Comment: check the EM/console if any of the OPMN-driven services are down. It's also possible that the analytics is querying the wrong repository instance.

Comment: This solved the issue for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351326/obiee-12c-cannot-login-to-analytics