# OBIEE 12c - cannot login to analytics

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, obiee, oracle-fusion-middleware, oracle-bi

Able to access OBIEE Console and EM but **unable to login to Analytics**. I have already scratched my head over searching for solutions all over. Any suggestion would help here.

**[Update]** - Not using DB Authentication or BISQLProvider. Tying to login with weblogic on a fresh installation of OBIEE

Steps I have tried:

- Checked bi server and admin server - Both running
- Checked deployments - all running
- Checked JDBC connection (from EM-> Weblogic Domain -> JDBC Datasources) for biplatform_datasource, mds_owsm, opss-data-source and wlsservices_datasource

EM Screenshot showing that no deployment or server is down:
[image]

Sawlog error below:

> [2017-04-11T23:49:14+08:00] [OBIPS] [ERROR:1] [] [saw.securitysubsystem.checkauthentication.runimpl] [ecid: ] [tid: 5480] [SI-Name: ] [IDD-Name: ] [IDD-GUID: ] [userId: ] Odbc driver returned an error (SQLDriverConnectW).
>       State: HY000.  Code: 10058.  [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred.
>        (HY000)
>       State: HY000.  Code: 73025.  [nQSError: 73025] The Oracle BI Server is currently unavailable for queries. Please contact your System Administrator to report the failure. (HY000)[[
>       File:checkauthentication.cpp
>       Line:1607
>       Location:
>           saw.securitysubsystem.checkauthentication.runimpl
>           saw.threadpool.asynclogon
>           saw.threads
>       ]]

**[Update 2]**: Even the BI Server (OBIS is up):
[image]
I also tried uninstalling OBIEE completely and reinstalling it back. I was able to login to analytics with admin user (weblogic) only once after config.cmd. And as soon as I restarted the services, analytics did not allow login for weblogic user. I feared that it could be due to hostname issue but the hostname is consistent as well.

**[Update 3 - Resolved]**:
Possibly the IP Address of the machine was creating a problem here. I set the machine to a static IP address and added a host name resolution in Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. This did the trick for me. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Comment: Please check `nqquery.log` and `nqserver.log` files under obis instance. Also check `bi_server1.log`, `bi_server1.out`, `bi_server1-diagnostic.log` under bi server. Under obips instance, check `sawlog.log` files. This one logs at the query level and may tell you something that is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[nQSError: 73025] The Oracle BI Server is currently unavailable for queries.

^-- Your screenshot only shows admin server and managed server. What's the actual status of the Oracle BI Server (OBIS)?

Target Navigation -> Business Intelligence -> biinstance -> Availability

[image]

Comment: Updated the post with a screenshot that all the bi servers are up.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 64bit (running with Vmware Fusion on a Mac PC)

Comment: Win7 is not a supported OS. It's desktop. Not server. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/fusion-middleware/documentation/fmw-122120-certmatrix-3254735.xlsx   If you are already using a VM then why not immediately go for Linux. Or even simpler: just take SamoleApp! Full installed, loads of examples and completely free. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/bi-foundation/obiee-samples-167534.html

Comment: Possibly the IP Address of the machine was creating a problem here. I set the machine to a static IP address and added a host name resolution in Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. This did the trick for me. Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the below error :

You are not currently signed in to the Oracle BI Server
If you have already signed in, your connection might have timed out, or a communications or server error may have occurred
To sign in again, click here. If the problem persists, please contact the site's administrator.

Solution:

first go to weblogic----> servers-->bi server--->  here change listen address to local host and port to analytics port and save it
later stop all servers and start it, it works

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue on OBIEE 11g, was unable to login to analytics with weblogic credentials and noticed following error logs.

error logs (sawlog): Cannot obtain Oracle BI Servers from either the primary Cluster Controller () or the secondary Cluster Controller () specified for the clustered DSN

Solution:

1. If your machine is in domain add following entries in your hosts file (make sure this 
   should be your first entry in host file).
2. Restart OPMN.
3. Restart BIServer (bi_server1)

This should solve error and now login with
hostname:9704/analytics